# Diagnose error in Access 2010 when using the runtime

Tags: runtime-error, ms-access-2010

I have an access application that is used by several users. Some have Access 2010 installed while others are using the runtime. Users that have Access can run the application just fine. However, those who uses the runtime have an error while using one of the form. The error is in french but roughly translate :

```
This application was stoped because of a runtime error.
It cannot continue and will be closed.
```

Obviously something's wrong, but since those with Access do not have this error, I can't debug the application and see what's wrong.

Is there some sort of log that is kept that have more information I could use for diagnosing. I get it that if those with the runtime would install Access it would solve the problem, but this is on a citrix server and those who don't have access do not have it because they were denied the access, for some reason, hence the runtime.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you got error traps on all procedures on the form? Have you checked references?

Comment: I can't really check the reference because it works 100% for this with Access and not for those who uses the runtime, so when I check them. I don't have the error. I do now think I have error trapping everywhere though, but the form doesn't call any code at beginning and more than one form does it, all excep the menu actually

Comment: Have you tried simulating the runtime environment on your development machine? You can do it with a command line switch or by renaming an accdb. It might help you trap the error.

Comment: I did not know that. I'll check it on the web. Thanks.

Comment: I tried force running as runtime on my development machine and it worked fine...

Comment: In that case I suspect that your users are missing a reference that you have.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308340 This has code to check missing references. Is it possible for you to run code on the runtime machines? BTW Early binding is often the cause of missing references.